# Android - Problem getResources() and getPackageName()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to use `setImageResources()` with a way to set a R.drawable.*variable_image_file*.
I have no idea how to do it, so I searched a little and i found this on many forums:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(character.getBmppath(), "drawable", getPackageName());
holder.pictureView.setImageResource(resID);
```

But here is my problem, Android Studio seems to not recognize `getResources()` and `getPackageName()`:

[image]

*(in this code, 'domas.png' is stored in the drawable folder)*

I don't find a solution online, can you please help to figure this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out if you don't have context in your adapter.

```
int resId =holder.firstNameView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("domas", "drawable", holder.firstNameView.getContext().getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `Context` to your class and then use `getResources` on it.

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("domas", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

I would suggest you setting image this way

```
    holder.pictureView.setImageDrawable(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            context,
            R.drawable.domas
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is in your `drawable` folder, you don't need to do anything fancy, this should work after providing a `Context` (I assume you can easily convert the below to Java from Kotlin):

```
context?.let {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           AppCompatResources.getDrawable(it, R.drawable.domas)
     } else {
           it.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.domas, null)
     }
```